# ajax, right way to do it and make it works?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hooks

I'm new to wordpress but have knowledge in php and javascript.

I read a lot of blogs about ajax call in wordpress. I also read some posts on this forum.
However, I still have some difficulties making an ajax call with wordpress.

It's a little confusing in my mind where `add_action` and hook must be written (inside my custom php function file or inside function.php file? or in an other way).

When my jquery script is called, `wp_ajax` is not defined...
I don't understand how my jquery script can get `wp_ajax` url or other variable from php before it is ran.

Here my different scripts:

In my function.php (I really don't know if I need to put this here or in my custom php file):

```
wp_enqueue_script('load_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/load_post.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', 1 );
wp_localize_script( 'load_post', 'wp_ajax',
        array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax_nonce') ));
```

In load_post.php

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_load_post', 'load_post_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post', 'load_post_callback');

function load_post_callback() {

if (isset($_POST['post_ids'])) {

    $nonce = $_POST['nonce']; 
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) ) {
        die ( 'Interdit !');
    }

    $ids = array(); 
    $ids[] = $_POST['post_ids'];

    $posts_per_page = 8;
    global $wp_query;
    query_posts(array('post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio'), 'post__not_in' => $ids, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page));
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    if ($post_type == 'post') {
        $post_type = 'blog';
    }
?>

//I do some stuff echo...

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    }
}
?>
```

And load_post.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    jQuery('#next-container').click(function() { 

        var IDs = [];
        $(".element").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });

        $('#next-container').html('loading');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wp_ajax.url,
            data: {  action: 'load_post',  
                     ajax_nonce: wp_ajax.nonce,
                    'post_ids': IDs,  
                  },  //{'post_ids[]': IDs },//'post_ids='+IDs,
            success: function(data) {
                    $('#next-container').html('');  
                    $container.isotope( 'insert', $(data));

                    }
                })
        })
})
```

Comment: is `load_post.php` included in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: yes like this : `require_once ($admin_path . "load_post.php");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functions.php file you should add an action to enqueue your scripts.

```
<?php
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'load_post', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/load_post.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '1.0', 
        1
    );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'load_post', 
        'wp_ajax',
        array( 
            'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_nonce' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However with this code, I still have the same problem to get wp_ajax variables... I'm on loacal server by the way, may be it's a pathname problem...

Comment: I really don't understand what I need to make it works... I spend so much hours on it... I miss a little thing I guess...

Comment: In the source code (in the head section) I don't see the `wp_ajax` variable. That's the reason I can't access it in my js script. What do I need to make it works?

Comment: @freaky - in your enqueue script call, you've set it to be output in footer (the `1` in the last argument) so you won't see it in head, it will be output in your theme when `wp_footer()` is called in your template. make sure that your theme is calling `wp_footer()`.

Comment: I solved it finally. It was a syntax error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having some problems, This is how I am calling the Fucntion via Ajax on Windows scroll

```
    $(document).live('scroll',(function(){
        // if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())  {
          LoadonButton();
        }
    }));
```

function LoadonButton (){
   var sessionCommentId =$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
   jQuery('#slick-slidetoggle').show();
    jQuery.ajax({ 
    type:'POST',
    url: 'http://dino-dev.com/foodie/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: 'HomeComments',
        number: '10',
        CommentLoadedID:sessionCommentId
        },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){

```
    jQuery(".comment_box:last").after(data);  
    },  
error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
```

}
  });  }

But I am having trouble with the plugins I am calling in HomeComments. The plugin functions are called but the options table is not populated or other things are missing.
How do I make sure my plugins are loaded properly. When I call this function directly it works perfectly.

Comment: answers should answer the original question. if you need help [ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).